# Ical.Net: Event's AsUtc flag is not updating correctly

Tags: timezone, ical-dotnet

I am facing this issue in Ical.Net Version=4.0.1.0 and lower, When we get "GMT-0500" in DTSTART/DTEND then it is giving same utc time as local time in AsUtc. But If I replace "GMT-0500" to "Canada/Eastern" manually in ics its giving correct utc time in AsUtc.

Following is not working fine -:

```
DTSTART;TZID=GMT-0500:20181213T190000
DTEND;TZID=GMT-0500:20181213T220000
```

Following works fine -:

```
DTSTART;TZID=Canada/Eastern:20181213T190000
DTEND;TZID=Canada/Eastern:20181213T220000
```

Answer (score 1):

- `GMT-0500` isn't a valid IANA time zone. [Here's the list of IANA time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). You want `Etc/GMT+5`.
- `Canada/Eastern` is deprecated. I suggest you use `America/Toronto` instead.

In general, I suggest you familiarize yourself with the actual time zone names instead of guessing as to what they might be, and hoping for the best.

There were also some bugs with caching `AsUtc` values, as I [noted in the release notes](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/blob/master/release-notes.md). I suggest upgrading to 4.latest. It [should be backwards compatible](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net#versioning).

Comment: Actually, the signs of etc time zones are inverted.  Edited for you.

Comment: @MattJohnson - I don't think so? `America/Toronto` is UTC-5 for ~half the year. UTC+5 would be... somewhere in eastern Europe/Asia, wouldn't it? (At any rate, I was using the OP's values.)

Comment: `Etc/GMT+5` == `UTC-5`.  This is a particular quirk of the IANA time zone names of the form `ETC/GMT*`.  See https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2018i/etcetera#L38-L44

Comment: DTSTART;TZID=GMT-0500:20181213T190000
DTEND;TZID=GMT-0500:20181213T220000, These are from ics returned by caldav server for icloud for some user's event. I know GMT-5 is equivalent to Etc/GMT-5. When I created event in America/Toronto on icloud.com it gave Canda/Eastern in ics which works fine. I have already check list of IANA timezones and I found that icloud.com returns some different timezones also like in format of GMT/+ and GMT/-, so for these cases when ics is parsed is doesn't updates AsUtc flag correctly.As these strings are returned by caldav server so,I don't have control overt it.